# Compute variance of random variable of unknown distribution $X$ from "repeated samples"

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable of unknown distribution, yet the goal is to find $var(X)$.

This could supposedly be achieved if you can "simulate two independent random variables with the same distribution" of $X$, say $X'$ and $X''$. The premise is that if you can somehow observe $E[(X'-X'')^2]=20$, you can base on this information and compute $var(X)$. This process is allegedly called *symmetrization*.

I have to confess I was assigned this homework problem but have no idea how to start. First of all, it baffles me why $X'$ and $X''$ would exhibit an expected squared difference of $20$ if they have the same distribution. It seems to me that $X'$ and $X''$ are "partial" distribution that resembles $X$ somehow, but I am supposed to infer the precise value of $var(X)$.

Any hint or explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
E(X^\prime-X^{\prime\prime})^2=E((X^\prime)^2-2X^\prime X^{\prime\prime}+(X^{\prime\prime})^2)=E(X^\prime)^2-2(EX^\prime)(EX^{\prime\prime})+E(X^{\prime\prime})^2.
$$
But $X$, $X^\prime$, and $X^{\prime\prime}$ all have the same distribution so
$$
E(X^\prime-X^{\prime\prime})^2=EX^2-2(EX)^2+EX^2.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It is clear to me now. Thanks! I guess I am supposed to exploit the fact that the expected value of all functions of $X$, $X'$, and $X'''$ are equal. I missed this point originally.